# Trouble using Doxygen's "documentation at other places" to document macros in multiple headers

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm working on documenting a large library of code (ANSI C, not C++), and have a platform-specific header for each of my target devices (various embedded devices and Win32).

I'd like to document the typedefs and macros those headers need to define, and I thought it'd work just fine after reading the [Documentation at other places](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands) section of the Doxygen manual.  I added the documentation to a common `platform.h` file that #includes the target's platform header.

My target platform headers (like `platform_win32.h` for example) include `@file` markup, and appear as expected in the file list.  When I click the file, it displays a list of typedefs and macros, but it only shows descriptions for the *ones that are unique to that header*.  Any macros/types that appear in multiple headers aren't documented.

Any ideas on what I can do about that?  I'd really like the descriptions to appear in multiple files.  Is this some sort of namespace issue?

EDIT (info for Jens):
Here's the crazy thing -- I have two macros documented side-by-side in `platform.h`.  The one that appears in `platform_foo.h` shows up in the list of globals, but the one that appears in `platform_win32.h` and `platform_bar.h` doesn't appear in the list.

None of the macro documentation appears in the `platform.h` file view, which makes sense since the macros and typedefs aren't used in that file -- it just holds the documentation.

Interesting: I just grepped the HTML help and it is listed in `globals_0x78.html` (0x78 = 'x', the first letter of the macro name).  I now think it might have something to do with namespaces.  Looking at the HTML source of a file, I see it listed as `group_name::MACRO_NAME`.

Will explore later -- time for another meeting.

Comment: do the defines in question appear in Files->Globals->Typedefs or not at all? What appears in the documentation of `platform.h`?

Comment: @Jens: Updated with additional info.  I think it's namespace related, and will explore a few things after some meetings this afternoon.

Comment: you said that it is C and not C++, don't you? There is a switch in the config to tell doxygen that this is C, I think.

Comment: @Jens: I have set the `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C` configuration option.  Also, the `SHOW_NAMESPACES` option doesn't appear to change the HTML output at all.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the [doxygen preprocessor](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) capabilities?

Comment: How would I use them to accomplish my goals?